# Error executing MSBUILD ReSharper CLI InspectCode task from TFS

Tags: c#, msbuild, resharper

When executing the ReSharper InspectCode .MSBUILD task file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
    <Import Project="C:\Download\JetBrains.ReSharper.CommandLineTools.2018.1.2\InspectCode.MsBuild.Targets" />

    <Target Name="Build">  
        <InspectCode ContinueOnError="False" SolutionFile="C:\source\xx\Dev\xx.Re.xx.sln" />
    </Target>  
</Project>
```

With the following command:

```
msbuild c:\temp\test.msbuild
```

**I receive the following error:**

> Error resolving component request for
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.IBuildEngine in
>   ComponentAccessCardinality::Single mode in context "for  in Container: JetEnvironment". Sequence contains more than
>   one element

**Complete error:**
https://pastebin.com/mCKsFtfH

The inspect code command finishes as expected, displaying a list of resharper errors/warnings, HOWEVER the fact that data has been written to the stderr output, means that the build fails.

So:

- Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
- Alternatively, can I pipe stderr to null somehow in order to ignore the errors?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue if you login the build agent machine and run msbuild command line manually?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yes - i can also recreate from my local PC.

Comment: It seems your issue is related to msbuild, not tfs. I modify the tag.